# Buscar los números pares de una matriz bidimensional

Tags: c#

Realizar una matriz 3x4 entera y determinar en qué posiciones exactas se encuentran los números pares. La hice pero no sé como hacer la parte de mostrar las posiciones exactas de los pares.

Esto es lo que llevo hecho:

```
int[,] numero;
numero = new int[3,4];

for(int fila = 0; fila < 3; fila++) {   
    for(int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
        Console.Write("Digite un numero: ");
        numero[fila,col] = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}

Console.Clear();

for(int fila = 0; fila < 3; fila++) {
    for(int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
        Console.Write(" " + numero[fila, col]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar lo que llevas hecho hasta ahora? (por favor, el código, no una imagen, o una foto, o una captura de pantalla, o una descripción).

Comment: Listo, ya puse lo que llevo hecho de codigo

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad alguna respuesta?

Answer (score 2):

Usa el operador módulo (`%`):

```
for(int fila = 0; fila < 3; ++fila)
    for(int columna = 0; columna < 4; ++columna)
        if (numeros[fila,columna] % 2 == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("El numero en [{0},{1}] es par.", fila, columna);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay otro modo de saber si un número es par o no, es mediante su representación en número binario.

Revisa el siguiente código:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[,] numero;
        numero = new int[3, 4];

        for (int fila = 0; fila < 3; fila++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
            {
                Console.Write("Digite un numero: ");
                numero[fila, col] = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        Console.Clear();

        for (int fila = 0; fila < 3; fila++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
            {
                Console.Write(" " + numero[fila, col]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Buscando Pares");

        for (int fila = 0; fila < 3; ++fila)
            for (int columna = 0; columna < 4; ++columna)
                if ((numero[fila, columna] & 1) == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("El numero en [{0},{1}] es par.", fila, columna);

    }
}
```

Hay un grupo de operadores poco usados: **Bitwise**, en esta línea:

```
if ((numero[fila, columna] & 1) == 0)
```

`numero[fila, columna]` representa un número 
`&` Es el operador Bitwise que vamos a usar.

En este caso, si un número es par, el último dígito de su forma binaria va a ser 0. y si es impar, su último dígito binario va a ser 1.

Ejemplo:

```
Número 60 en binario es: 111100
Número 13 en binario es:   1101
```

Un poco de teoría:

Los operadores Bitwise soportados por C# se listan en la siguiente tabla. Supongamos que la variable A contiene 60 y la variable B contiene 13.

```
| Operador | Descripción                                                                                                                                                       | Ejemplo                                                                          |
|----------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| &        | Binary AND Operator copia un bit al resultado si existe en ambos operandos.                                                                                       | (A & B) = 12, which is 0000 1100                                                 |
| |        | Binary OR Operator copia un bit si existe en cualquiera de los dos operandos.                                                                                     | (A | B) = 61, which is 0011 1101                                                 |
| ^        | El operador XOR binario copia el bit si está configurado en un operando pero no en ambos.                                                                         | (A ^ B) = 49, which is 0011 0001                                                 |
| ~        | El Operador del Complemento de Binarios es unario y tiene el efecto de "voltear" bits.                                                                            | (~A ) = -61, which is 1100 0011 in 2's complement due to a signed binary number. |
| <<       | Operador de Desplazamiento Binario Izquierdo. El valor del operando izquierdo se mueve a la izquierda por el número de bits especificado por el operando derecho. | A << 2 = 240, which is 1111 0000                                                 |
| >>       | Operador de Desplazamiento Derecha Binario. El valor del operando izquierdo se mueve a la derecha por el número de bits especificado por el operando derecho.     | A >> 2 = 15, which is 0000 1111                                                  |
```

¿Recuerdan las clases de lógica digital? ¿Computeras lógicas? Bueno, aquí es donde se emplea.

Cuando se trabaja con binarios, se recomienda hacer agrupaciones de 4 dígitos y para dar un orden, se completa con ceros a la izquierda.

Ahora, viendo en código:

```
using System;

namespace OperatorsAppl {

   class Program {

      static void Main(string[] args) {
         int a = 60;            /* 60 = 0011 1100 */ 
         int b = 13;            /* 13 = 0000 1101 */
         int c = 0; 

         c = a & b;             /* 12 = 0000 1100 */ 
         Console.WriteLine("Linea 1 - Valor de c es {0}", c );

         c = a | b;             /* 61 = 0011 1101 */
         Console.WriteLine("Linea 2 - Valor de c es {0}", c);

         c = a ^ b;             /* 49 = 0011 0001 */
         Console.WriteLine("Linea 3 - Valor de c es {0}", c);

         c = ~a;                /*-61 = 1100 0011 */
         Console.WriteLine("Linea 4 - Valor de c es {0}", c);

         c = a << 2;      /* 240 = 1111 0000 */
         Console.WriteLine("Linea 5 - Valor de c es {0}", c);

         c = a >> 2;      /* 15 = 0000 1111 */
         Console.WriteLine("Linea 6 - Valor de c es {0}", c);
         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

Esto genera como resultado:

```
Linea 1 - Valor de c es 12
Linea 2 - Valor de c es 61
Linea 3 - Valor de c es 49
Linea 4 - Valor de c es -61
Linea 5 - Valor de c es 240
Linea 6 - Valor de c es 15
```

Explicaciones adicionales

Considerando que A = 60 (111100 en binario) y B = 13 (1101  en binario)

```
c = a & b;
```

Esto se entiende mejor si lo ven modo operación, un & es verdedero (1) siempre y cuando las variables sean verdaderas (1), como 60 en binario tiene 6 dígitos y 13 en binario solo 4, al 13 en binario le agregamos ceros a la izquierda:

```
 111100 (60)
 001101 (13)
=001100
```

Y este número binario 1100 en decimal es 12.

El operador `|` OR resulta falso (0) cuando todas las variables son falsas. En esta ocasión voy a agrupar 4 dígitos dejando un espacio y rellendo de ceros a la izquierda.

```
 0011 1100 (60)
 0000 1101 (13)
=0011 1101
```

Nótese que es casi el mismo 60 en binario, +1 bit al final, da 61.

```
c = a ^ b;
```

El operador `^` XOR se comprende así: es verdadero (1) cuando todas sus variables son diferentes. Agruparé nuevamente en 4 dígitos y rellenando con ceros a la izquierda.

```
 0011 1100 (60)
 0000 1101 (13)
=0011 0001
```

Traducimos del binario al decimal y nos da 49.

```
c = ~a;
```

El operador `~` tiene el efecto de "voltear" bits.

```
a =  0011 1100
~a = 1100 0011
```

Ahora, para que haya salido -61... -inserte música de suspenso aquí- hay todo un tema que se tiene que revisar pues es el "complemento a dos", de por sí la respuesta ya se extendió mucho y tampoco sé cómo explicar bien este tema en particular, por lo que te voy a pedir disculpas y bueno, aquí un punto de partida https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_a_dos

```
c = a << 2
```

El operador `<<` va a mover 2 lugares a la izquierda, es decir, de `111100`, se va a generar 2 ceros a la derecha, quedando  `11110000` y éste número traducido a decimal es 240.

```
c = a >> 2
```

El operador `>>` va a mover 2 lugares a la derecha, es decir, de `111100` los últimos 2 de la derecha van a desaparecer, quedando `1111` y éste número traducido a decimal es 15.

Answer (score 0):

Como bien dijo PaperBirdMaster usando el operador módulo (%) se puede saber si el numero es par o no.

```
        int[,] numero;
        numero = new int[3, 4];

        for (int fila = 0; fila < 3; fila++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
            {
                Console.Write("Digite un numero: ");
                numero[fila, col] = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("Los numeros pares son:");

        for (int fila = 0; fila < 3; fila++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
            {
                if (numero[fila, col] % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} --> fila: {1} columna: {2}", numero[fila, col], fila, col);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Entrada:

```
Digite un numero: 1
Digite un numero: 2
Digite un numero: 3
Digite un numero: 4
Digite un numero: 5
Digite un numero: 6
Digite un numero: 7
Digite un numero: 8
Digite un numero: 9
Digite un numero: 10
Digite un numero: 11
Digite un numero: 12
```

Salida:

```
Los numeros pares son:
2 --> fila: 0 columna: 1
4 --> fila: 0 columna: 3

6 --> fila: 1 columna: 1
8 --> fila: 1 columna: 3

10 --> fila: 2 columna: 1
12 --> fila: 2 columna: 3
```