# Mostrar los divisores de un número en una matriz de 3x3

Tags: c#, .net, matrices

Tengo que realizar una matriz de 3x3 donde pido un número en consola y muestre los divisores de ese número llenando la matriz e imprimir en matriz.

Ya hice varias matrices y los muestra normal con números aleatorios, sumas de diagonales, pero en esta no sé si me falta algo, no lo he logrado aún.

Dejo el código que realicé, que me busca los divisores y los imprime, pero no en forma de matriz de 3x3.

```
int numero;
int[,] matriz = new int[3, 3];

Console.WriteLine("DE QUE NUMERO DESEA VER LOS DIVISIBLES");
numero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine($"LOS DIVISORES DE {numero} SON:");

for (int divisor = 1; divisor <= numero; divisor++)
{
  for (int fila = 0; fila < 1; fila++)
  {
    for (int columna = 0; columna < 1; columna++)
    {
      if (numero % divisor == 0)
      {
        matriz[fila, columna] = divisor;
        Console.WriteLine($" {matriz[fila, columna]} ");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: pero necesitas una matriz para asignar los valores divisibles ? o solo lo haces porque necesitas verlos como matriz, porque son cosas diferentes

Comment: Cuando el programa me pregunta de que numero deseo ver los divisibles y ejemplo ingreso 100 me debe imprimir en matriz los numeros divisible de 100
ya logre que los imprima pero no logre que los muestre en matriz de 3 * 3.
Necesito que los imprima asi:
 1    2     4  
5    10    20  
25   50   100

Comment: Ver los divisibles del numero en forma de matriz de 3 * 3

Comment: pero estas mostrando una lista de divisibles no una matriz, repito es un tema visual o necesitas que se asignen los resultados a una matriz ?

Comment: Hay mostre lista porque no me imprime en matriz.

Necesito que en consola se impriman los divisibles en una matriz.

Comment: Asi dice el taller.
Crear una matriz de 3x3 y llenarla con los divisores del número que se indique
(debe llenarla por filas). Los datos se deben ingresar por pantalla. Muestre la
matriz.

Ya lo logre solo me falta que se imprima la matriz con los resultados osea los divisibles de dicho numero

Comment: estas seguro que la matriz se carga correctamente? porque en la otra pregunta cambiaste la poiscion del if

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Buscar los números pares de una matriz bidimensional](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/281536/buscar-los-n%c3%bameros-pares-de-una-matriz-bidimensional)

Answer (score 0):

Aconsejaria separes la accion de calcular los valores de la matriz con la accion de mostrar los datos

entonces por un lado tendrias

```
int numero;
int[,] matriz = new int[3, 3];


Console.WriteLine("DE QUE NUMERO DESEA VER LOS DIVISIBLES");
numero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine($"LOS DIVISORES DE {numero} SON:");

int fila = 0;
int columna = 0;

for (int divisor = 1; divisor <= numero; divisor++)
{
    if (numero % divisor == 0)
    {
        matriz[fila, columna] = divisor;

        if(columna < 3){
            columna++;
        }
        else{
            columna = 0;
            fila++;
        }
    }
}
```

lo cual mencionas calcula bien la matriz de valores

Pero para mostrar los datos podrias evaluar

```
for (int fila = 0; fila < 1; fila++)
{
    List<int> linea = new List<string>();
    for (int columna = 0; columna < 1; columna++)
    {
        linea.Add(matriz[fila, columna]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", linea));
}
```

con lo cual vas uniendo los valores que tendra una linea y al terminar lo muestras

Otra posibilidad seria

```
for (int fila = 0; fila < 1; fila++)
{
    List<int> linea = new List<string>();
    for (int columna = 0; columna < 1; columna++)
    {
        Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", matriz[fila, columna]));
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: edite la respuesta proponiendo un codigo diferentes para cargar la matriz

Answer (score 0):

El 3 de alto y el 3 de ancho hay que ponerlos en una variable, ya que si en el futuro se quiere aumentar dichos valores, solo hay que cambiar el valor de la variable.

Además agrego una variable llamada `id_divisor_actual`, que va contando la cantidad de divisores que agregó a la matriz.

La posición en donde va el divisor la calculo de esta forma:

- y: `id_divisor_actual / alto`
- x: `id_divisor_actual % alto`

Si se sobrepasa la cantidad máxima de divisores, es decir, si se llena la matriz, hago un `break`.

```
if(id_divisor_actual >= ancho*alto){break;}
```

Voy mostrando cada número junto con un tabulador (`\t`) hasta llenar la fila, luego muestro un salto de línea:

```
Console.Write(divisor + "\t");
if( x == ancho-1 ){
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```

Código:

```
int numero;
int ancho = 3;
int alto = 3;
int id_divisor_actual = 0;

int[,] matriz = new int[ancho, alto];

Console.WriteLine("DE QUE NUMERO DESEA VER LOS DIVISIBLES");
numero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine($"LOS DIVISORES DE {numero} SON:");

for (int divisor = 1; divisor <= numero; divisor++)
{
    if (numero % divisor == 0)
    {
        if(id_divisor_actual >= ancho*alto){break;}

        int x = id_divisor_actual % alto;
        int y = id_divisor_actual / alto;

        matriz[y,x] = divisor;

        Console.Write(divisor + "\t");
        if( x == ancho-1 ){
            Console.Write("\n");
        }

        id_divisor_actual++;
    }
}
```